# Iterate with forloop instead of foreach

Tags: foreach, loops, musixtex

I have this `{C/4/a/n,D/4/b/n,E/4/c/n}`

This is how I iterate it with foreach:

```
\foreach \x\y\w\z in {C/4/a/n,D/4/b/n,E/4/c/n} {
        \x - \y - \w - \z
    }
```

But I need to do it with forloop.
It is important to be able to separate the x,y,w and z and not use packages that have to be installed in overleaf such as expl3 or similar.

Comment: I don't quite understand your final sentence.  expl3 is already installed in Overleaf, and the foreach already separates the x, y, w, and z.  Could you explain what you're trying to do?  How would you do it with a for loop, if you could invent the syntax?

Comment: It's a bit complicated to explain, my code is too extensive to give it as an example, but the point is that for some reason using foreach in my code makes the musixtex lirycs mess up, and when using forloop it works very well. An equivalent of what I want would be for example in javascript: var list=[[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h]];
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){functionAny(list[i][0],list[i][1],list[i][2],list[i][3]) }

Comment: @ArturoRodas -- You don't say in your question that you're using `musixtex`, or indeed what the purpose of your question is.  That really would be helpful.

Comment: `expl3` is now part of LaTeX itself, so it doesn't require *any* package, available in Overleaf or not. Does `musixtex` provide `forloop`? Is there any remaining objection to `expl3`?

Comment: You can use LaTeX's  `@for` or do a` \loop ... \repeat`   ` \newcount\n
\n=0
\loop
  \advance\n by1
    \texttt{\number\n, } 
  \ifnum\n<30
\repeat`

Comment: your question is not at all clear and appears backwards. expl3 is not only installed on overleaf it's preloaded into latex and so requires no package at all. whereas latex does not have commands called `\forloop` or `\foreach` so they would need to be defined. what apart from the name do you want a command called `\forloop` to do?

Answer (score 1):

The following defines a function to loop over lists with two different modes. The first is a simple comma separated value list, and `#1` refers to the current list item (this is just a `\clist_map_inline:n`).

The second mode takes a delimiter for the sublists as an optional argument, and if it's given you can access the submembers with `#1{<n>}`, and the complete list with `#2`. The whole thing works without groups (unlike `\foreach`), so I hope it works for you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g__arturo_nested_level_int
\NewDocumentCommand \ForEach { +o +m +m }
  {
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
      { \clist_map_inline:nn {#2} {#3} }
      { \__arturo_foreach:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3} }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__arturo_foreach:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g__arturo_nested_level_int
    \__arturo_foreach_aux:ccnnn
      { __arturo_foreach_code_ \int_use:N \g__arturo_nested_level_int :nn }
      { l__arturo_foreach_items_ \int_use:N \g__arturo_nested_level_int _seq }
      {#1} {#2} {#3}
    \int_gdecr:N \g__arturo_nested_level_int
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__arturo_foreach_aux:NNnnn #1#2#3#4#5
  {
    \cs_set:Npn #1 ##1 ##2 {#5}
    \seq_clear_new:N #2
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#4}
      {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn #2 {#3} {##1}
        #1 { \seq_item:Nn #2 } {##1}
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__arturo_foreach_aux:NNnnn { cc }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ForEach{a,b,c,d}{#1\par}

\ForEach[/]{C/4/a/n,D/4/b/n,E/4/c/n}{#1{1} - #1{2} - #1{3} - #1{4} (from #2)\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a TeX solution. I do not understand what exactly you want to do, but you can start from here.

```
\bgroup
\def\for#1\endfor{\def\body{#1}\iterate}
\def\iterate{\body\let\next=\iterate\else\let\next=\relax\fi\next}
\newcount\n
\n=0
% Example usage
\for
   \advance\n by1
     \number\n,   
   \ifnum\n<30
\endfor
\egroup

\bye
```

Recursion and if statements make a programming language Turing complete.